# Error:(16, 23) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/icon')

Tags: android, android-drawable

This is first time I developing an Android App with Bluetooth device and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.
Please help, thanks!

The Android Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.ilovemii.myapplicationblue"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />

    <application
        android:name="com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name="lhu.stevenpon.f713.com.hotlifebluetoothspp"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="lhu.stevenpon.f713.com.DeviceListActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/select_device"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
        <activity
            android:name="lhu.stevenpon.f713.com.DeviceListActivity01"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/select_device"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

[Screenshot of Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYNux.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to:

```
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
```

Since, based on your sceenshot (and the recommended way now) you have icons in mipmap folders.

Answer (score 0):

place your app icon in mipmap folder and

change

```
<application
        android:name="com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

to

```
<application
        android:name="com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication"
        android:icon="@mipmap/your_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
```